# why blockingSingle crashes but blockingFirst works

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm simply reading a value from the app's shared preference so there should be only 1 value emit.

SharedPrefAsync:

```
Observable<Boolean> getSomeValue() {
  // retrieve the value asycnhronously
}
```

Usage:
`sharedPrefsAsync.getSomeValue().blockingFirst()` works but `sharedPrefsAsync.getSomeValue().blockingSingle()` seems to crash the app with no error log

I've read [the official documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) but I'm unclear about the different between `blockingSingle` and `blockingFirst`.

How do find out what was actually wrong with using `blockingSingle` here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "official documentation" of RxJava is its [JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/) and [Wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki) pages. The ReactiveX site is an aggregation of Rx implementations and isn't as up to date regarding RxJava as it could be (plus, we update the documentation more often to be more precise on the concept and behavior).

[`blockingFirst`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingFirst--) takes the first element if there is at least one and ignores the rest:

[image: blockingFirst]

[blockingSingle](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#blockingSingle--) expects exactly one item, otherwise it throws an exception:

[image: blockingSingle]

So, double-check your `getSomeValue()` chain, it must be emitting more than one values